# Очистка Gulp от проекта

Tags: gulp

К примеру я сделал проект на сборке `Gulp`, выгрузил папку `dist` и всё сделал, а что делать с файлами *html* и *css* которые остались в папке `app/src`, где я и писал все стили. Я хочу начать новый проект на этой же сборке, неужели все руками чистить или я что-то не понимаю?
Хотелось бы услышать развернутый ответ по шагам.

Comment: «Я хочу начать новый проект на этой же сборке» — продублировать директорию с проектом, очистить `src` и начать заново?

Comment: @Igor Rusinov А что насчет зависимостей npm? Каждый раз же куча ненужных файлов остается.

Comment: `npm prune` удалит все зависимости, которые не указаны в `package.json`.